# IntelliJ slow to highlight identifier under caret

Tags: intellij-idea

Currently using latest IDEA Ultimate 2016.1, when I click on a variable or function name there's about a .5s delay before the identifier under caret is highlighted in a file.

Is there a configuration option somewhere to reduce this delay? It works much faster in WebStorm, closer to .25s to highlight.